# Junit mocking for Linked MultiValueMap

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to mock a method with a LinkedMultiValueMap, but without any success. To cut a long story short, I've just begun to work with Mockito and Junit testing a few days ago, and I actually don't know what I'm doing. I'll provide my test method code, with my tryout to write a mock test.

```
@Service
public class VaultService {
public VaultService() {

        String baseUrl = System.getenv("VAULT_HOST") + "/api/v" + System.getenv("VAULT_API_VERSION");
        String userAgent = System.getenv("APPLICATION_NAME") + "/" + System.getenv("APPLICATION_VERSION");

        webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, userAgent)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1200000)
    public void authenticate() {
        LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> login = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        login.add("username", System.getenv("VAULT_USERNAME"));
        login.add("password", System.getenv("VAULT_PASSWORD"));

        webClient.post()
                .uri("/auth")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(login))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(AuthenticationResponse.class)
                .map(authenticationResponse -> {
                    setSessionId(authenticationResponse.sessionId);
                    return authenticationResponse;
                })
                .block();
    }
}
```

And here's my failed try to write a mock test:

```
class VaultServiceTest {
    private WebClient webClientMock;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        webClientMock = mock(WebClient.class);
    }

    @Test
    void authenticate() {
        VaultService vaultService = new VaultService();
        LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> testAuthenticate = mock(LinkedMultiValueMap.class);
        when(testAuthenticate.get("password")).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Never mock a collection type like `LinkedMultiValueMap`.  Just make a real one.

Comment: Or any type that's just plain data with no behavior to modify. @LouisWasserman

Comment: @LouisWasserman >> You mean, to make a map out of LinkedMultiValueMap?

Comment: I mean to make a real `LinkedMultiValueMap`.  Don't mock it, construct it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, It doesn't make sense to mock either value object or any type of objects that doesn't contain any logic or is time consuming or needs a lot of resources or is not under test ( is external or is used by your functionality but is not your functionality).

Said this, I usually consider two categories of 'testing':

- testing functionalities that invoke other functionalities
- testing functionalities that has their own logic, then, for a given input they do have a definite output

The service you are testing belongs to the first category, so I would test that the web service you invoke is called with the right parameters.

So, I don't know Spring, but you should use a series of

```
Mockito.verify(mockObject).methodToCall(parameter1, parameter2);
```